# UI does not respond outside ApplicationUI

Tags: c++, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm new developing BlackBerry applications and it's really hard for me understand how it works because the way to develop for BB differs a lot of Android or iOS developing.

Here is my issue: I've created a registerPage.qml and a registerPageController (with it's .hpp and .cpp). I would like the app starts with the registerPage.qml and call form the qml some methods i wrote in the .cpp file.

If I create the qml document outside the ApplicationUI(), the page is displayed nice, but the buttons does not respond.

I think with the code is easily to understand:

applicationui.cpp

```
ApplicationUI::ApplicationUI() : QObject()
{
    m_pTranslator = new QTranslator(this);
    m_pLocaleHandler = new LocaleHandler(this);

    bool res = QObject::connect(m_pLocaleHandler, SIGNAL(systemLanguageChanged()), this, SLOT(onSystemLanguageChanged()));
    Q_ASSERT(res);
    Q_UNUSED(res);

    onSystemLanguageChanged();

    // --> OPTION 1 (what I want) <--
    /* If I init the register page here, the page is
       displayed ok, but buttons does not respond.
       The RegisterPage initialization code is below. */
    // RegisterPage registerPage;

    // --> OPTION 2 <--
    /* If I create the registerPage here, buttons respond
       but the _register param is not setted properly*/
       QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///registerPage.qml").parent(this);
       qml->setContextProperty("_register", this);

       AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
       Application::instance()->setScene(root);
}
```

registerPage.hpp

```
class RegisterPage: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    RegisterPage();
    virtual ~RegisterPage() {}

    Q_INVOKABLE void initRegistration();
};
```

registerPage.cpp

```
RegisterPage::RegisterPage()
{
    /* With this initialization, buttons does not respond!!*/
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///registerPage.qml").parent(this);
    qml->setContextProperty("_register", this);

    // Create root object for the UI
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();


    // Set created root object as the application scene
    Application::instance()->setScene(root);
}

void RegisterPage::initRegistration()
{
    qDebug() << "start registration!";
}
```

registerPage.qml

```
Page {
    Container {
        Button {
            text: "Accept"
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            topMargin: 100.0
            appearance: ControlAppearance.Primary
            onClicked: {
                console.log("click!!")
                _register.initRegistration()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I load an qml file, associate it an .cpp and call functions from qml? Why the buttons does not respond?

Thanks a lot, and sorry if this is the basis of BlackBerry development, but this is making me crazy.

**----------------**

**EDITED**

Finally thanks to @Filip Hazubski to help me to find the final solution.

In *applicationui.cpp*

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///registerPage.qml").parent(this);
AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();

RegisterPage* registerPage = new RegisterPage(this, root);
qml->setContextProperty("_register", registerPage);

Application::instance()->setScene(root);
```

and in *registerPage.cpp*

```
RegisterPage::RegisterPage(QObject *parent, AbstractPane *root) : QObject(parent)
{
    phoneTextField = root->findChild<TextField*>("phoneTextField");
}
```

Passing the AbstractPane as param we can find the qml elements into the registerPage.cpp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but maybe my answer will help you.

In *applicationui.cpp* instead of:

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///registerPage.qml").parent(this);
qml->setContextProperty("_register", this);

AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
Application::instance()->setScene(root);
```

try:

```
QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///registerPage.qml").parent(this);
AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();

RegisterPage* registerPage = new RegisterPage(this);
qml->setContextProperty("_register", registerPage);

Application::instance()->setScene(root);
```

and in *registerPage.hpp*

```
RegisterPage();
```

change to

```
RegisterPage(QObject *parent = 0);
```

and in *registerPage.cpp* change

```
RegisterPage::RegisterPage()
{
    /* With this initialization, buttons does not respond!!*/
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///registerPage.qml").parent(this);
    qml->setContextProperty("_register", this);

    // Create root object for the UI
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();


    // Set created root object as the application scene
    Application::instance()->setScene(root);
}
```

to

```
RegisterPage::RegisterPage(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that also, but when I try to call a method of RegisterPage from the qml file the program crashes. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @kemmitorz I will try to improve it.

Comment: @kemmitorz No problem. I would be glad to help. Try my solution now. Maybe now it will be working.

Comment: Thanks @Filip. Your solution works, but i've modified it a little to find the qml objects into the cpp file ;). I've edited my code with the final response.

Comment: @kemmitorz I am glad to hear that. I suspect that the problem was that your `QObject` (`RegisterPage` class) had no parent specified.